# How to fetch values in a url using curl?

Tags: php, http, curl

I want to fetch values from a url along with some parameters.I use the following code

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.xzxxz.ca/api/Listing.svc/PropertySearch_Post?ApplicationId=1&BathRange=0-0&BedRange=0-0&CultureId=1&CurrentPage=1&LatitudeMax=60.500524687194485&LatitudeMin=56.46248967233933&LongitudeMax=-27.4658203125&LongitudeMin=-145.5029296875&MaximumResults=9&ParkingSpaceRange=0-0&PriceMax=0&PriceMin=0&PropertyTypeId=300&RecordsPerPage=9&SortBy=1&SortOrder=A&TransactionTypeId=2&viewState=m&cookiecheck=1");
$fp = fopen("collected.txt", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

while using this code '405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.' is shown.Is this due to the .svc file format or mistake in parameters passing?

Comment: If you copy and paste the URL directly into a web browser, do you get the same error or does it work?

Comment: while pasting the URL in the web browser the same error is displayed.

Comment: This is not [tag:data-mining] (no statistical analysis happening here). It's not even [tag:web-scraping] yet, but curl and http, actually. (You are doing a `POST`, the web site only allows a `GET`)

Comment: Is there option to fetch vvalues from this URL?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the remote web server is refusing the connection because you are trying to POST data to it.

Try removing the following line...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

This should change the HTTP method from POST to GET.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is most likely something to do the the server your posting to and not your PHP code.